# Get if user is following a page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get if user following or not the page. I'm trying like this:

```
public function get_following()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(Followers::class, 'user_id')->where('type', '=', 1)->where('follower_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
}
```

But this return null and I follow this page (got the item on table)...

dd($page)

```
Page {#305 ▼
  #relations: array:3 [▼
    "ptag" => Tag {#309 ▶}
    "get_following" => null
    "links" => Collection {#318 ▶}
  ]
```

DB:

```
followers.user_id = (pages.id), follower_id = (auth user), type = (1)
```

Comment: please, add code where you fetching the data

Comment: Check out querying relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: Why does your `followers.user_id` map to `pages.id`?